# Check to see when applet is repainted or resized

Tags: java, applet

How can I see if an applet has been resized or repainted? Is there a event listener that I can use?

Comment: The size of an applet should be set in HTML in, usually in px.  As such, they would normally be 'unresizable'.

Comment: It wasn't just an Applet that I was hoping to implement, but good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the following methods and simply chain each call to the superclass implementation.

[`resize(Dimension)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#resize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)

[`resize(int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#resize%28int,%20int%29)

[`paint`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29)

**Example**

```
@Override
public void resize(Dimension d) {
  super.resize(d);
  System.err.println("Resized applet to new dimensions: " + d);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To see if it is being repainted, I suppose you could override its paint method, or better the paintComponent method of its contentPane (if a JApplet), but why are you even interested in listening for this?

To listen for a change in size, don't override resize. Instead use a ComponentListener, as that's what it's for.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the component listener to check for a resize.